# A good reference for Bochner spaces

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis

I am looking for some references on Bochner spaces containing basic stuff such as measurability, convergence and $L^p$ theory. I already have the [Analysis in Banach Spaces: Volume I](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319485195) book which covers quite well the theory but I would like some other reference, one possibly containing more applications on evolution problems and convergence in $L^p(S,X)$. Any suggestions?

Comment: What about the classics Dunford/Schwartz or Diestel/Uhl?

Comment: Diestel, J.; Uhl, J. J., Jr. Vector measures. Mathematical Surveys, No. 15. American Mathematical Society, Providence, R.I., 1977.